# How to get UITextfield value from custom UItableViewCell. If UITableviewCell have multiple UITextFields without using tag property

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCell (dynamically created) for Billing address and Shipping address .I want to get UITextField  value .How I can get its value without using tag property.Following is screen of my UITableViewCell-[image: Custom UITableViewCell]

cellForRowAtIndexPath code is as-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(isShippingShow){
        switch (indexPath.section){
            case 0:
            {
                CardListCell *cell = (CardListCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                return cell;
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                NewCardCell *cell = (NewCardCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                return cell;
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            {
                PayAddressCell  *cell = (PayAddressCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PayAddressCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.txtCountry.delegate = self;
                cell.txtCountry.inputView = _pickerView;
                [self setTextFieldAccessoryView:cell.txtCountry];

                return cell;
            }
                break;
            case 4:
            {
                SettingCell *cell = (SettingCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SettingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                [cell.swSetting addTarget:self action:@selector(changeState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

                return cell;
            }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    else{
        switch (indexPath.section){
            case 0:{
                CardListCell *cell = (CardListCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CardListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                return cell;
            }
                break;
            case 1:{
                NewCardCell *cell = (NewCardCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                return cell;
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                PayAddressCell  *cell = (PayAddressCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PayAddressCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.txtCountry.delegate = self;
                cell.txtCountry.inputView = _pickerView;
                [self setTextFieldAccessoryView:cell.txtCountry];

                return cell;
            }
                break;
            case 3:
            {
                SettingCell *cell = (SettingCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SettingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                [cell.swSetting addTarget:self action:@selector(changeState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

                return cell;
            }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    return [UITableViewCell new];
}
```

Custom Cell class is as-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewCardCell : UITableViewCell


@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCardHolderName;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCardNumber;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtExpDate;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCVV;

@end


@interface CardListCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCount;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCardNumber;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgCardIcon;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSelectCard;
@end


@interface SettingCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCaption;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UISwitch *swSetting;
@end


@interface PayAddressCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtAddress;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCity;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtState;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtZipcode;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *txtCountry;
@end
```

Comment: Update your question with your cellrowatindex tableview delegates method

Comment: why you don't want the tag Property? it will makes easy to fetch uitextfield

Comment: Why not textfields in Scrollview? 
It would be more easier

Comment: @Saheb Singh I have no need of scrollView. I already have UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can track your value inside TextField's delegate **textFieldDidEndEditing** method :

NSString *strAddress; // in interface

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview; //track cell's view hierarchy
    if (cell isKindOfClass:[PayAddressCell class]) {
        PayAddressCell *settingCell = cell;
        if (textField == cell.txtAddress) {
            strAddress = textField.text; // your address textfield's value
        }
        // you can check all textfield as above .
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVO to bind your textfield.text to your model data.

Answer (score 0):

Create Cell Model class corresponding to each cell -

```
@interface CellModel : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *zipcode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *country;

@end
```

In textfield Delegate

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
cellModel.address = textField.text;
// or cellModel.city = textField.text;
// or cellModel.state = textField.text;
// or cellModel.zipcode = textField.text;
// or cellModel.country = textField.text;
  }
```

Do this in all tableView cell which you have created.